# Pseudo Class 'nth-child()' not working with ':hover"

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to use the pseudo class `:nth-child()` with `:hover` but it seems to not work for me. I am trying to change the colour of one element to green when hovered over, but it highlights all of them. I also tried without the hover and none of the colours change.

```css
ul {
    background-color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
ul li {
    margin: 0 2em;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}
a:nth-child(2){
color: green;
}
```

```html
<ul>
      <li><a href="#">Easy</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Medium</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Hard</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Insane</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: All of your links are first child. You need to use the nth-child on the 'li'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because the `a` isn't the 2nd child - it is an only child of it's parent `li`. What you are looking for is the `a` child of the 2nd `li` element. You can get that like this:

```
li:nth-child(2) a{ color: green; }
```

Then for the hover, either of these work with the code in your question. It depends on what you want to target with the hover:

```
// When the <a> in the second li is hovered, change it's colour
li:nth-child(2) a:hover{ color: green; }

/* OR */ 

/* When the second li is hovered, change the colour of the <a> it contains */
li:nth-child(2):hover a{ color: green; }
```

**Working Example** (using different colours to show it working):

```css
ul {
    background-color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
ul li {
    margin: 0 2em;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}

/* change colour of 2nd link */
li:nth-child(2) a{
    color: blue;
}

/* change colour of 2nd link on hover */
li:nth-child(2):hover a{
    color: green;
}

/* change colour of 3rd link on hover */
li:nth-child(3) a:hover{
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
      <li><a href="#">Easy</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Medium</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Hard</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Insane</a></li>
</ul>
```

**Reference**: [Mozilla MDN Docs for nth-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child)

Comment: I was wondering for this line of code `li:nth-child(2):hover a{color: green;}` why there has to be the a selector there for it to work? doesnt the nth child select it already?

Comment: @Tony The `li.nth-child(2)` will select the second `li`, however you want to change the *link* colour which is the `a` element in the `li`. So when the second `li` is hovered over, this line will change the colour of the `a` it contains.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this code may help you. And learn more about pseudo-classes and elements using this link.[Click here to learn about CSS Pseudo-classes](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp)

```
li:nth-child(2):hover a{
    color: red;
}
```